# Sorting array after user input not working and to display after

Tags: python, arrays, sorting

```
# the main
def main():
    # calling list and variables
    golfScores = []
    index = 0
    SCORES = 10

    # enter scores 10 times
    while (index <= SCORES - 1):
        scoreInput = int(input('Enter score: '))
        golfScores.append(scoreInput)
        index = index + 1
    
    # calling module to sort with 2 parameters passed
    bubbleSort(golfScores, SCORES)

    # print the final result
    print('The sorted order is:', golfScores)

# going through the array to sort
def bubbleSort(golfScores, SCORES):
    maxElement = SCORES - 1
    while (maxElement >= 1):
        index = 0
        while (index <= maxElement - 1):
            while (golfScores[index] > golfScores[index + 1]):
                swap(golfScores[index], golfScores[index + 1])
            index = index + 1 
        maxElement = maxElement - 1
    return golfScores

# a & b passed as ref values to swap
def swap(a,b):
    temp = 0
    a = b
    b = temp
    return a,b

# call the main to run
main()
```

Whenever I would run the whole thing, it takes inputs 1-10 and displays fine, but upon any other one, it seems to get stuck and I have to keyboardinterupt to get out of it.  It also seems to print the stuff in the array, but not in the order

So I feel like its the bubbleSort that's not working.. I've tried thinking about the swap layout for this and was wondering if it had to do with this.

Trying to accomplish

> User input: 3, 2, 1, 4, 6, 5, 8, 7, 10, 9

> Output: The sorted order is: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

Comment: Do any of the answers work for you?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is actually in your swap function. In Python, ints are pass-by-value, so your swap function does not affect the values of a & b in your bubbleSort function.

Try deleting the swap function, and replace your line:

```
swap(golfScores[index], golfScores[index + 1])
```

With:

```
golfScores[index], golfScores[index + 1] = golfScores[index + 1], golfScores[index]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while (golfScores[index] > golfScores[index + 1]):
            swap(golfScores[index], golfScores[index + 1])
```

This should be:

```
if (golfScores[index] > golfScores[index + 1]):
            swap(golfScores[index], golfScores[index + 1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Python does not have pass by reference. To swap two variables, use `var1, var2 = var2, var1`. You can improve the input statement by using `map` and `split` like so `golfScores = list(map(int, input().split(", ")))`, as you are currently reading the entire line as one element of the list.

Revised code:

```
def main():
    # calling list and variables
    SCORES = 10
    golfScores = list(map(int, input().split(", ")))
    if(len(golfScores) != SCORES):
        return
 
    # calling module to sort with 2 parameters passed
    bubbleSort(golfScores, SCORES)
 
    # print the final result
    print('The sorted order is:', golfScores)
 
# going through the array to sort
def bubbleSort(golfScores, SCORES):
    maxElement = SCORES - 1
    while (maxElement >= 1):
        index = 0
        while (index <= maxElement - 1):
            while (golfScores[index] > golfScores[index + 1]):
                golfScores[index], golfScores[index + 1] = golfScores[index + 1], golfScores[index]
            index = index + 1 
        maxElement = maxElement - 1
    return golfScores
```

[Demo!](https://ideone.com/EgHWG8)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem you were having was created due to your condition resulted in an infinite loop at some point. I changed a code a bit, do check it out and if any confusions do ask. As with this, you wouldn't need to use swap function.

```
def main():
    # calling list and variables
    golfScores = []
    index = 0
    SCORES = 10

    # enter scores 10 times
    while (index <= SCORES - 1):
        scoreInput = int(input('Enter score: '))
        golfScores.append(scoreInput)
        index = index + 1
    # calling module to sort with 2 parameters passed
    golfScores = bubbleSort(golfScores, SCORES)

    # print the final result
    print('The sorted order is:', golfScores)

# going through the array to sort
def bubbleSort(golfScores, SCORES):
    maxElement = SCORES
    while (maxElement >= 1):
        index = 0
        while (index < maxElement - 1):
            if golfScores[index] > golfScores[index + 1] :
              temp = golfScores[index]
              golfScores[index] = golfScores[index + 1]
              golfScores[index + 1] = temp
            index += 1
        maxElement = maxElement - 1
    return golfScores

# a & b passed as ref values to swap
def swap(a,b):
    temp = 0
    a = b
    b = temp
    return a,b

# call the main to run
main()
```